# sum from second to seventh row

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to create a query that gets 2 parameters pre-status and status. from here i want to sum up the duration.
this is my table:

```
   Title_Id    Media_Info_Id Rank                 Title_Pre_Status_Name                              Title_Status_Name                                  duration    Activity_Date
----------- ------------- -------------------- -------------------------------------------------- -------------------------------------------------- ----------- -------------
49090       -1            1                    New Work Order                                     Annotate WO                                        0           2016-11-15
49090       -1            2                    Annotate WO                                        New Work Order                                     69309       2017-01-02
49090       -1            3                    New Work Order                                     Annotate WO                                        1           2017-01-02
49090       -1            4                    Annotate WO                                        Ingest WO                                          4           2017-01-02
49090       -1            5                    Ingest WO                                          QC WO                                              1353        2017-01-03
49090       -1            6                    QC WO                                              New Work Order                                     33390       2017-01-26
49090       -1            7                    New Work Order                                     Annotate WO                                        971         2017-01-27
49090       -1            8                    Annotate WO                                        Ingest WO                                          27665       2017-02-15
```

so for instance i'm getting as in put:

pre status = 'Annotate WO'
and status = 'New Work Order'

i should get back the sum of rows 2-7.
any one have any idea of a good method of doing this without too many inner selects?

Comment: What is the logic by which your pre and status result in selecting rows 2-7?

Comment: ist a users input and he can choose what ever starting status and ending status he wants. the logic if there are several changes with the same status he will take the min\max

Comment: What version of SQL Server is this?

Comment: this is MS SQL Server 2012

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i manged to do it this way:

```
SELECT 
    t.Title_Id,
    sum(duration) as duration,
    date = (select min(Activity_Date) from Dwh_Fact_Title_Activity_Ranks_V t1 where t.Title_Id = t1.Title_Id and t1.Title_Pre_Status_Name = @pre_Statuse)
FROM  Dalet_DWH.dbo.Dwh_Fact_Title_Activity_Ranks_V t
where
t.Rank>=(select 
            min(t2.Rank) 
         from Dalet_DWH.dbo.Dwh_Fact_Title_Activity_Ranks_V t2 
         where 
            t.title_id = t2.Title_Id 
            and 
            t2.Title_Pre_Status_Name = @pre_Statuse) 
and 
t.Rank<=(select 
            max(t2.Rank) 
        from Dalet_DWH.dbo.Dwh_Fact_Title_Activity_Ranks_V t2 
        where 
            t.title_id = t2.Title_Id 
            and 
            t2.Title_Status_Name = @status)
group by t.Title_Id
```

it works but i think the run time is to long.

feel free to help and improve the algorithm.

thanks all

Answer (score 1):

You want all records from the minimum ID for a given pre status till the maximum ID for a given status. Hence: find the minimum ID; find the maximum ID; get the records.

```
select sum(duration)
from mytable where rank between
  (select min(rank) from mytable where title_status_name = @prestatus)
  and
  (select max(rank) from mytable where title_status_name = @status);
```

You should have these indexes for the query to run fast:

```
create index idx1 on mytable(title_status_name, rank); -- finds min and max rank for 
                                                       -- a status quickly

create index idx2 on mytable(rank, duration); -- finds the records based on rank quickly
                                              -- and contains the duration to add up
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your logic correctly, then something like this should work:

```
select t.*
from t 
where t.rank >= (select min(t2.rank) from t t2 where t2.title_id = t.title_id and t2.Title_Pre_Status_Name = 'Annotate WO') and
      t.rank <= (select max(t2.rank) from t t2 where t2.title_id = t.title_id and t2.Title_Pre_Status_Name = 'New Work Order');
```

Comment: the thing is i dont know what input i get

Comment: This is a terrible idea. The expense of the query would grow with the number of rows since each row would end up having the predicate clause being fired.

Comment: @clifton_h . . . This query is fine.  Probably the most optimized solution with an index on `t(title, title_pre_status_name, rank)`.

Comment: @Gordon.Linoff that is a true statement, that you may have the most optimized, of the available answers, but i can show you still a better way through CTEs and/or variables. Why not set the min/max values in a variable or cte table that is then compared to the original table? Then you eliminate row operations except for simple greater/smaller bit comparisons.